# What is the best way to keep a list of items in order with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok this is my scenario. I have a "tour" that has many "stops". I need to keep each stop in order and allow my users to move those stops around. I can't figure out the best way or the "best practice" to keep a list of items in order. One idea I had was to create a column called "position" that would keep track of what position each stop was in, however when using jQuery UI sortable it seemed like it expected me to implement the ordered list by sending the ids via ajax to my server in the order they should be. This, is fine, however I don't know how my server is supposed to keep track of which order each stop should be in based on the order of the id's sent in.

So basically, what is the best way to a list of items in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [acts_as_list](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/List/ClassMethods.html) feature in rails that @Devin M mentioned.

Here is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists)-cast about it.

Answer (score 2):

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_sortables.html

Comment: I would give acts_as_list a try

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_list is pretty good for this.

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

It in fact creates a position column as you conceived.